# How can I conditionally replace the opening line of a block of code?

Tags: python

My program needs to check whether the OS is Linux or Windows, opens the file in home of that user and do the same code (in this case `for` loop) after detecting the OS.

So I know this code will work:

```
from sys import platform


def test():
    if platform == 'linux':
        with open('$HOME/test.txt', 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                print(line)
    elif platform == 'win32':
        with open(r'%userprofile%\\test.txt', 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                print(line)
```

But this duplicates the code in the body of the loop. I'd like to be able to replace the `with` line according to the `if` condition, but this fails:

```
from sys import platform


def test():
    if platform == 'linux':
        with open('$HOME/test.txt', 'r') as file:
    elif platform == 'win32':
        with open(r'%userprofile%\\test.txt', 'r') as file:

            for line in file:
                print(line)
```

I get an error that reads:

```
    elif platform == 'win32':
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

How can I make this work, so as to avoid duplicating the loop code?

Comment: You need to restructure the logic of your code so that the `for line in file` process happens *outside* of your `if` statements. Perhaps your `if/else` block can simply set a variable to the appropriate filename, and then use that in a subsequent `when` block?

Comment: Yes, just set a variable to the file name and only open the file after that decision has been made.

Comment: @larsks the answer of question is written by `Mechanic Pig` and works.

Comment: `if` statements do not "pre-process" the code. They are part of the code, so they run normally like everything else. That means that everything you put inside the `if` block *has to be able to stand on its own*, and similarly for the `else` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider assigning a string in a judgment statement:

```
def test():
    if platform == 'linux':
        filename = '$HOME/test.txt'
    elif platform == 'win32':
        filename = r'%userprofile%\\test.txt'
    else:
        ...

    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use path library to abstract yourself from operating system standards in the case you're doing something easy.

In that case you can simplify you logic and readability to the following code

```py
from pathlib import Path


def test():
    filename = Path.home() / "test.txt"

    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line)
```

source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=home#pathlib.Path.home